# JSONPath expression for an array of multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

I have a json payload that looks like this

```
{
   "data":{
      "methods":[
         [
            {
               "p_id":"01",
               "description":"Test01",
               "offline":true
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "p_id":"02",
               "description":"Test02",
               "offline":false
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "p_id":"03",
               "description":"Test03",
               "offline":true
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I write a JSONPath expression to get the "p_id" where "offline"= false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter expression which selects all elements in an object or array that match the specified filter. For example, `[?(@.offline === false)]` will match any object if its `offline` property is strictly `false`.

So, if the object is always in the same place, you could do:

```
$.data.methods.*[?(@.offline === false)].p_id
```

Or, if you want to look for any object where `offline` is `false` and fetch `p_id`, you could use a recursive descent with the filter expression:

```
$..[?(@.offline === false)].p_id
```

Note: I used [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) in my examples so it will only match with a boolean false. If you don't need/want that you could instead simply use a `!` to negate the filter. E.g. `[?(!@.offline)]`